# How to access or activate public preview for Form Recognizer v2.1?

Tags: preview, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I would like to try the new feature to **name a custom model** and **Model Compose** like mentioned here: [Form Recognizer v2.1 description](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/form-recognizer-v2-1/). Now I am searching desperately for the way to **get access to the public preview**. Further do I have to upgrade my labling tool with a new image in a specific way to get access to the preview version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an existing Form Recognizer instance, you will have access to the [v2.1 preview](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1-preview-1) already.

You need need to upgrade your labeling tool, as documented in the [train custom model with labels quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool?tabs=v2-1). Afterwards you will have access to Model Compose.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't found the link for the preview image in the documentation. Now it works. :)